# What are the lyrics to this song translated into english?

Tags: узус, транслитерация, английский

Улыбка - Крошка енот - Moscow Boys' Choir DEBUT
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANNQrVKUjws

The video says its from the song or poem Smile from "Baby Raccoon".

Comment: https://lyricstranslate.com/ru/ulybka-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-smile.html